# Using AngularJs how to write code for Sucess and Failure

Tags: angularjs

How to apply Success And Failed in AngularCtrl

```
$scope.Btncall = function () {

        var xx = MyService.GetDatafromApi();
        xx.then(function (d) {
            $scope.Employee = d.data;
        }

        ),success(function (success) {
            alert('ok');
        })
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please add details and articulate the problem or what you are trying to achieve, mention the relevant code that doesn't work as you expect, or show the errors you have, and show your own efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: if xx.then(function (d) {
        $scope.Employee = d.data;
    } is Error then we wrote  as  ,function(Error){  alert('Error')  then how to load success

Comment: Super unclear question, but it looks like you are working with a promise from a http request. Your code has an extra closing parenthesis and the success callback should be the first parameter. Also reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood is that you're asking how to handle a promise return success/fail like the one you get from the $http request service, so here's below an example:

```
$http.get('http://freegeoip.net/json')
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //TODO When request Success
    console.log(data);
    $scope.Employee = data;
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //TODO When request Failed
    console.log(data); //Server Response values if there's any
    $scope.Employee = [];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code which helps you.

```
  $scope.Btncall = function () {
      MyService.GetDatafromApi().success(function (data, status,headers)    
      {
        $scope.Employee = data;
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers) {
         $scope.Employee = [];
      });
    }

//Call Btncall Function..
$scope.Btncall();
```